# Is there a site that compares "effective" rake?

Tags: online, cash-game, rake

I am trying to look for sites or comparisons of the top or major online poker sites and their "effective" rake, for both cash games and for tournaments.

I do not want to deal with promotions or rakeback and points and freerolls.

In banking, for loans, there is the stated per-month interest rate, sometimes a per-annum, and the add-on rates, but there is also something called the "effective" interest rate.

I would like to compare all the sites according to the same criteria, so if there are promotions, maybe that can be factored in.

I understand this may be a duplicate question, but my question is asking more about the "effective" rake if the games are otherwise the same.

Let's pretend I want to start my own online poker site (and let's pretend that I can do it) and I have no other promotion except that my rake will be lower than the average lowest effective rake. So I see, for example, PokerStars rake is 4.5% across the board (less for lower stakes), would I get a lot of players if my rake is only 3.9%, for example, and I have no other promotions? Assuming that my site is also fair (no god mode, no super users, anti-collusion, fair shuffling with mathematical proof, etc.)

Dabs

Comment: By lowest effective rake, I assume you mean the average rake that one would pay. Assuming you have different rates across the SB/BB levels, that would rather depend on what level your punters choose to play. Obviously you could tweak this on the fly but it would be bad for business if it turned out you were promoting a rate that most of your players weren't actually getting because say, they all chose to play the smaller stake tables.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no such sites which compares ALL rake, since rake differs from Sit 'n' to to cashgame etc etc.  One thing is that on different sites you have different skill levels of poker players which attracts or disattracts someone. If you go for bwin or something, a page where you can bet your money on running horses or whatever...poker is just a sidepart and these people aren't good in general. Here are the newbies feeling well, because they don't end up losing after some games. What I want to say about that is, that people don't always compare each sites. Pokerstars is well known for it's name and having skilled players. I guess it's always about promotion. Lowering your rake will not automtically make your site "better" or more attractive for everyone. But i guess your idea is fine and you can promote this.
So you say "Lower Rake than every other site you know", that will attract people I guess.

Try it and find out, good luck